# CSV Import showing weird characters - PHP CSVLeague

Tags: php, csv, thephpleague

I am trying to import csv. And, here is my csv file for test.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LU4SHG_EbSj9OTRXRakNHgllZD45iaS3/view?usp=sharing

I am providing exact file so that the file structure / encoding may not changed if I paste the csv text here.

I am using CSV League https://csv.thephpleague.com/ and I have code for import as follows:

```
        $header_row = 0;
        $filename = 'test_extra.csv'
        $csv_file_path = storage_path('app/files/').$filename;
        if (!ini_get("auto_detect_line_endings")) {
            ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", TRUE);
        }
        $csv = Reader::createFromPath($csv_file_path, 'r');

        //trying to conver encode to utf-8
        $csv->addStreamFilter('convert.iconv.ISO-8859-15/UTF-8');

        $csv->setHeaderOffset($header_row);

        $sample_data = $csv->fetchOne($header_row);
        print_r($sample_data);
```

But, It is printing data as:

[image]

This is totally weird because the first row possess data something like:

```
‌0858,‌0858-A1,‌One Bedroom All.a1,1,1,702,2,‌1X1,0
```

Is there something I might be missing?

Comment: Cannot look at that file, you didnt open it up so anyone can read it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry my bad, please have a look now.

Comment: File is already encoded UTF-8, it has BOM EF BB BF

Comment: See the end of this [page](https://csv.thephpleague.com/) you shoudl first check its encoding using `$input_bom = $csv->getInputBOM();`